# Hadoop 2.2.0 mapreduce job not running after upgrading from hadoop 1.0.4

Tags: java, hadoop

I have upgraded my hadoop version from 1.0.4 to 2.2.0. The mapreduce job was running fine earlier. Now i have added almost all jars provided for hadoop 2.2.0. Still it gives me this exception. Let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.<clinit>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolEngine(RPC.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:166)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: still jar is missing which contains class com.google.protobuf.ServiceException

Comment: How are you executing jar ?

Comment: I have main method in my controller class. Running from the main method. I have added hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar which has this class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check your `protobuf` dependency. AFAIR Hadoop 2.x needs 2.5.x (please check your hadoop dependencies) and you could just take outdated one because of some external component.
2. Just for note: if your job uses `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package it could be binary incompatible with Hadoop 2.x. You should recompile in this case. There should be no such issue with "old" API `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`. But I'd recommend recompile in any case.

Hope this at least help.