# NoCLassDefFound error in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, protocol-buffers, noclassdeffounderror

I am using hadoop 2.4.1 version. I am trying to run a mapreduce job which moves data from local system to hdfs cluster(output directory). If I set the output directory as my local system path, the program is running fine. But when I set the output directory as a path in hdfs cluster I am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.<clinit>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolEngine(RPC.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:160)
    at s1.run(s1.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at s1.main(s1.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

I saw some posts which stated the issue could be related to protobuf dependecy. 
[Hadoop 2.2.0 mapreduce job not running after upgrading from hadoop 1.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672546/hadoop-2-2-0-mapreduce-job-not-running-after-upgrading-from-hadoop-1-0-4)
I am using hadoop commons jar 2.5.2 which has the protobuf. Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure 2.5.2 contains protobuf.ServiceException. It does not appear in JARFinder. You could try to import protobuf as a another jar.

Comment: @TheJavatar : Thanks ! Will do that !

Comment: @TheJavatar: I added protobuf java -2.4.1 jar and ran the program. It gave the following exception. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$CompleteRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 ..

Comment: It looks like hadoop(not protobuf) interferes with java.lang(tries to override a final method), that is pretty strange.

Comment: @TheJavatar : I found a similar issue http://grepalex.com/2014/02/09/flume-and-hadoop-2.2/ . So this issue is in regard to protobuf version variation?

Comment: That's my guess. You might have to play around with those version to make it work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Made it working ! Found that there were some jars of 2.2 version which were incompatible with the current version. When i updated those, the program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you compile zhe *.java use default java CLASSPATH is ok.
Edit the hadoop_env.sh
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}
restart the hadoop server

Answer (score -1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown by jvm at runtime when a class is not present in classpath.

Check your classpath.

Check also this answer. Could be useful if you solved the NoClassDefFoundError [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672546/hadoop-2-2-0-mapreduce-job-not-running-after-upgrading-from-hadoop-1-0-4)